# Mobility gem default fallback for all missing translations

Tags: ruby, mobility

I'm wondering how it's possible to set a default fallback for all missing translations at once for the Mobility gem (https://github.com/shioyama/mobility). As far as I understood the documentation the `fallbacks` config has to be done explicitly for each and every locale, e.g. `fallbacks {:de => :en, :fr => :en, :ja => :en}`. I already tried `fallbacks :en` (and some variations) but could not get the expected result.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Nevermind. I just used `I18n.available_locales` in a proc for `fallbacks` config option and this way built a default mapping for all locales.